# Use of CommandBars.ExecuteMso problems

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Berry is a Range of multiple cells from another excel file and Melon is a table in a powerpoint slide. I am attempting to paste Berry into the ppt table, by first selecting the cell(3,2) on the ppt table. After doing so, I would like to unselect anything. and select cell(3.7).

The following code successfully pastes the range into the table with Cell(3,2) in the top left corner.

```
Berry.Copy
Melon.Table.Cell(3, 2).Shape.Select

Lemon.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")
```

However, when i try the following code, the range gets pasted into the table with Cell(3,7) in the top left corner. I would think the range will get pasted as per earlier followed by merely have the Cell(3,7) selected without any pasting.

```
Berry.Copy
Melon.Table.Cell(3, 2).Shape.Select

Lemon.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle")

Melon.Table.Cell(3, 7).Shape.Select
```

It seems like the ExecuteMso code always get executed as the last line of code.
Pardon my english and I thank you for your time and help.

The following is the complete code:

```
Sub Auto()

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Dim apple As Workbook
Dim grape As Workbook
Dim orange As Range
Dim Kiwi As Shape 'Shape
Dim Peach As Object
Dim Berry As Range
Dim pear As Range
Dim Lemon As PowerPoint.Application 'PPApp
Dim LemonJuice As PowerPoint.Presentation 'PPpres
Dim Melon As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim LCounter As Integer


Set grape = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\206521654\Documents\Automate     vba\try.xlsx")
Set apple = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\206521654\Documents\Automate vba\Monthly Report\Msia\Weekly Channel Ranking Broken Out.xlsx")
Set orange = apple.Sheets("Periods").Range("A5:C25")
orange.Copy
grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:D23").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3").Formula = "=D3/C3-1"

Set SourceRange = grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3")
Set fillRange = grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E23")
SourceRange.AutoFill Destination:=fillRange
grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E23").NumberFormat = "0%"

grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:E23").Font.Name = "Calibri"
grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:E23").Font.Size = "11"
grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3:D23").NumberFormat = "0.000"
For Each Cell In grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E3:E23")
If Cell.Value < 0 Then
    Cell.Font.Color = vbRed
Else:
    Cell.Font.Color = vbBlue
End If
Next
Set Berry = grape.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:E23")
Berry.Copy

Set Lemon = New PowerPoint.Application

Set LemonJuice = Lemon.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\206521654\Documents\Automate vba\Automate test.pptx")


Set Melon = LemonJuice.Slides(1).Shapes(8)

Melon.Table.Cell(3, 2).Shape.Select
Lemon.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteExcelTableDestinationTableStyle"


Melon.Table.Cell(7, 2).Shape.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Why does the CommandBars.ExecuteMso get executed at the very end?

Comment: What happens when you step through each line of code using the debugger, does the issue still occur?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me Cody. The issue does not occur when i run the debugger!!  It happens when I run the sub using the green triangle :/ Why is this so? Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: Remove the parentheses from the "paste..." You don't need them.

Comment: Tomorrow I might be able to look into it more... But basically you might need to either just add a sleep timer in there or a while loop to check when it's finished ... As a quick fix. What you should do though is probably look at the msdn documentation and figure out how to transfer the data a different way. Why do you need to use the paste function? Why can't you just take the values from one table and put it in the other?

Comment: I am not familiar with an alternative code to paste the values into the desired cells in the table in the powerpoint slide. I have attached my full code btw. Thank you for your help. whats an alternative way to transfer the values?

Comment: Here's an article I found about using tables in powerpoint. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744161.aspx

Comment: I googled "msdn powerpoint" and got to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff899336.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is some example code that takes an open excel document and open powerpoint and copies over  the table data from excel into a NEW table in powerpoint.

You ***MUST*** add the powerpoint reference to your excel VBA.

Put something in cells 2,2 and 2,3 in excel, it should be pasted over into a new table in powerpoint.

**Note:** Since I merely mashed a bunch of code from the documentation together, you get some unnecessary functionality such as creating a new table every time and modifying all tables, but I hope that this code serves as a necessary base for showing you how you can avoid using msoExecute.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestCopyData()

Dim sSht As Worksheet
Set sSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slide


'Open PPT if not running, otherwise select active instance
On Error Resume Next
Set PPApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If PPApp Is Nothing Then
    'Open PowerPoint
    Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPApp.Visible = True
End If

PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes _
    .AddTable NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4, Left:=10, _
    Top:=10, Width:=288, Height:=288

Dim sh As Integer
Dim col As PowerPoint.Column
With PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    For sh = 1 To .Shapes.Count
        If .Shapes(sh).HasTable Then
            For Each col In .Shapes(sh).Table.Columns
                Dim cl As PowerPoint.Cell
                For Each cl In .Shapes(sh).Table.Rows(2).Cells
                    cl.Shape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 125, 0)
                Next cl
                .Shapes(sh).Table.Columns(1).Width = 110
                .Shapes(sh).Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sSht.Cells(2, 2)
                .Shapes(sh).Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sSht.Cells(2, 3)
            Next col
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Cody. I will definitely give the code a go on Monday and get back to u.

Comment: Glad to hear  it :)